# can't delete files from directories created on a specific period of time

Tags: php

I have an image sharing website , when user is uploading image my code would created direcory based on date ( year/month) on fly

```
    $year = date('Y');
    $month  = date('m');
    $path = ("images/{$year}/{$month}/");
    if (!file_exists($path))
    mkdir($path,0777,TRUE);
```

So recently i've noticed i cant delete some of my images (via php code) , after looking into it some more i've found that some of my directories are not writable despite the fact that i can upload image in them( or at least i could in those year/month)

So basically it's becuz of the directory that i can't delete images .

i wrote this little code to checkout dirs

```
for($i = 1 ; $i < 13 ; $i++){
    if($i <= 9 )
    $i = '0'.$i;
    echo    $file = base_path('/files/images/2013/'.$i.'/');
    echo '  # IS_DIR ==>' ; var_dump(is_dir(($file)));
    echo '  # IS_WRIT ==>' ; var_dump(is_writable(($file)));
    echo '<br />';
}
```

so here is the result :

[image]

```
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/01/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/02/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/03/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/04/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/05/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/06/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/07/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/08/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/09/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>false
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/10/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>false
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/11/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>false
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/12/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>false
```

[image]

```
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2014/01/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>false
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2014/02/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2014/03/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2014/04/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2014/05/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2014/06/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>true
```

It seems like something has happened to my directories from 2013/09 to 2014/01

Even though some changes in permissions / GID / UID  are obvious in the pictures , it doesn't seem to be the problem cuz some of the writable dirs have the same settings .

i've no idea why this is happening , i'll appreciate any help or suggestion

Comment: is it on a shared server or dedicated server ?

Comment: @SyedQarib it's a vps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you're trying to delete them through PHP, but those directories have permissions set to `755` and owner:group to `sitecom:sitecom`. It means that `apache` cannot delete them.

Try to change (if you have permissions) owner:group to `apache:apache` and then you'll be able to delete them from PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you have created this folder via FTP:

```
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2014/01/
```

And now you can't change it via PHP, because the user which PHP is using doesn't have the privileges to delete that folder because that user is not the file owner.

Change the permission for this folder:

```
/home/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2014/01/ # IS_DIR ==>true # IS_WRIT ==>false
```

Connect via FTP with the user who is the file/folder owner and you should be able to change the owner to the user which PHP is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Recursive` checkbox from your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the files inside the folder which you are trying to delete, might be opened in other place either through code and which haven't been closed due to some reason.

Comment: i cant delete any of the files plus directory is not writable

Answer (score 0):

You never showed us the code that does the deleting, but I would suggest with php do an exec() command, then rm with a -f flag.

```
exec("rm -rf images/2014/{$i}/");
```

-f flag forces the issue, -r deletes subdirectories therein.